# How to hide group in ExpandableListView in android

Tags: android

In ExpandableListView if I only have one group. I want to hide that group, only the group's data show that. Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 13):

1) Hide the Group indicator with:

```
android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
```

2) return an empty FrameLayout for the groups you want to be empty like this:

```
    @Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //By default the group is hidden
    View view = new FrameLayout(context);

    String groupTitle = getGroup(groupPosition).toString();

    //in case there's more than one group and the group title is not empty then show a TextView within the group bar
    if(getGroupCount() > 1 && !groupTitle.isEmpty()) {

        view = getGenericView();
        ((TextView)view).setText(groupTitle);
    }

    return view;

}
```

3) Call expandGroup for the groups you are not showing the group bar:

```
expandableListView.expandGroup(GROUP_ID);
```

4) If you want to show a group indicator you have to add an ImageView programmatically from the getGroupView method. Check this blog post for more info on hiding/showing group indicator: [Hiding group indicator for empty groups](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/hiding-group-indicator-for-empty-groups.html)

Comment: Thanks for the trick. This is the only answer it worked for me. Anyway, isn't it a bit hacky? I don't understand why isn't an "offcial" way to hide the header.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and this solveed my issue.
In your Listview's adapter add the following to the getGroupView.

```
if (groupPosition == 0) {
     convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_layout, null);

} else {
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_indicator_cell,null);
}
```

This will blank the 0th groupof the list.

Where blank layout is a layout with some view inside having layout_height=0dp.
It works!

Comment: I just now tried this, and it indeed works, but it causes some strange behavior with the remaining visible groups in the expandable list. Clever solution, nonetheless!

Comment: simple and briliant. tnx!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning a empty layout, I travel through all children in the layout and call `view.setVisibility(View.Gone)` when there is no data.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LinearLayout lo;

    if (convertView != null) {
        lo = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    } else {
        lo = (LinearLayout) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_group_header, parent, false);
    }

    int visibility = mData.size() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
    for (int i = 0; i < lo.getChildCount(); i++) {
        lo.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(visibility);
    }
    return lo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent iew vlayout params hieght to zero in your BaseExpandableListAdapter so that you can hide you parent

Comment: I've tried 

parent.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
parent.invalidate();

but it doesn't do anything:

I've tried:
parent.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0));
but it launches a ClassCastException :(

Have you actually tried this or you guessed?